# Debugging custom membership provider - An unexpected error has occurred.

Tags: development, wss-3.0, debugging, membership-provider, visual-studio-2013

I used this video tutorial to get started and created a custom membership provider:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/BomBom/Building-your-own-MemberShipProvider-in-ASPNET-20-and-use-it-in-SharePoint

I'm having trouble getting VS to debug.

I've done the following:

- Created c# library project for .NET 3.0 and inherited MembershipProvider
- Set signing in project settings
- Built dll in debug
- Put dll in the web app bin folder
- Used sn -Tp and put public key in web app web.config
- Added my provider to web.config

  ```
  <membership defaultProvider="AndyProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="AndyProvider" 
         type="CustomMembershipProvider.AndyMembershipProvider, CustomMembershipProvider, 
         Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ee9911c9483b5f81" 
      />
    </providers>
  </membership>
  ```
- Set Single Sign On and provider name in central administration

[image]

- Attached VS 2013 to w3wp.exe processes

But when I access the site I get `An unexpected error has occurred.`. I'm expecting visual studio to catch an exception. It appears I'm attached correctly.

[image]

I don't see any errors in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\LOGS

Here's the membership provider code (all unimplemted except test code in ValidateUser)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Configuration;

namespace CustomMembershipProvider
{
    public class AndyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        string strName = null;
        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return strName;
            }
        }

        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool EnablePasswordReset
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            return true;
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I upped the log level to verbose and saw this:

```
Application error when access /, Error=Provider name cannot be null or empty.   
  at System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderCollection.Add(ProviderBase provider)     
  at System.Web.Security.MembershipProviderCollection.Add(ProviderBase provider)     
  at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders(ProviderSettingsCollection configProviders, ProviderCollection providers, Type providerType)     
  at System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize()     
  at System.Web.Security.Membership.get_Provider()     
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHttpHandler.OverrideExecuteUrlPath()     
  at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExe...
```

So I added this and the error went away:

```
namespace CustomSharePointProvider
{
    public class AndyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "AndyMembership";
            }
        }
```